# Constrains for ImageView is not working

Tags: ios, uiimageview, autolayout, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have used `AutoLayout` with one of my `UICollectionView` I'm facing issue with height and width for imageView. I have added `UIImageView` in my `UICollectionViewCell` like following with below constraints.

[image]

`UICollectionViewDataSource` methods.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 100
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    var width = Int((collectionView.frame.size.width - 30) / 4)
    if width % 2 != 0 {
        width += 1
    }        
    return CGSize(width: CGFloat(width), height: CGFloat(width))
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    print("Cell Size - \(cell.bounds)")
    print("ImageView Size - \(cell.imageView.frame)")
    return cell
}
```

But when I run this the `ImageView` is always coming with `70X70` no matter on which device I will run but `UICollectionViewCell` size is increasing and decreasing on different devices.

**On iPhone 6 it will looks like below.**

[image]

I have set `backgroundColor` of `UIImageView` to white color and red color for `UICollectionViewCell` so that it will give batter understanding the console log for Cell and ImageView Size is as below.

```
Cell Size - (0.0, 0.0, 86.0, 86.0)
ImageView Size - (5.0, 5.0, 70.0, 70.0)
Cell Size - (0.0, 0.0, 86.0, 86.0)
ImageView Size - (5.0, 5.0, 70.0, 70.0)
```

Please any one help me why the imageView size is not increasing or decreasing according to the `UICollectionViewCell`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why x and y ... there is no need for that I think???

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 I have already try without that also but it will not working.

Comment: I see This Size Class is selected in your storyboard.  If you select All, can you still see the constraints?

Comment: @CarienvanZyl Don't understand what you try to say.

Comment: In the constraints section, underneath the visual representation of the constraints, there are a segment control, between All and This Size Class.  If you define the constraints for This Size Class only, they are not applied to the other size classes as well.  If you open the constraint, Installed will not be checked, but one size class, ex. wR hC might be checked.  See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Size-ClassSpecificLayout.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching a bit I have came up with the following way to solved this issue of `AutoLayout` with `UICollectionViewCell`. From Xcode 6 `CollectionViewCell` doesn't show the `contentView` in interface builder, so in the `awakeFromNib` of cell I have set its `autoresizingMask` and it works like charm.

```
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {
  @IBOutlet
  var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
      super.awakeFromNib()
      //Below line solved my problem
      self.contentView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in size inspector of collection view ,set Estimate Size to None

Comment: How simple it was! But it took so many hours to find it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set constraints as below screenshot;[image]

Comment: I have already added these constrains with 5 spaces from top,bottom,left and right, check the question once again.

Comment: yes this is the constraints issues so you need to remove all existing constrains and set only 4 constraints as above screenshot.

Comment: in which comment you have to explain this ?

Comment: Read the first of question this is already suggested by El capitan and i have also replied on this.

Answer (score -1):

**Center horizontally and Center vertically Constraints should not be there when pin to parent all the sides**(Top,Bottom,Leading & Trailing) were given for your Image view.

Either **remove Center horizontally and Center vertically Constraints**
Or Top,Bottom,Leading & Trailing and give **equal widths and heights as parent along with centre vertically and horizontall**y.

Seems removing Center horizontally and Center vertically Constraints will solve your problem for sure,give it a try.

Hope that helps.
Good luck.

Comment: I have already tried this check the second comment of question.

Comment: I Have already tried with equal width and equal hight the only solution that helps me is setting the autoresizingMask for contentView of collectionViewCell.

Comment: Ohhh anyway,got the solution finally na.thats what matters :)